# replace underscore with space asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iqueryable

Hi I have a function that returns Iqueryable and which is binded to dev express gridview. The name field that is being return contains _ in it. I want to replace all the _ by space when it is rendered on the browser. How ca I do it.? Do i need to write a function for that which will again return Iqueryable and that i can bind to the gidview.??

This is the code which has _ in it.

```
IQueryable actions = from act in CS.actions
                                 select new { Id = act.Id, Name = act.Name, CatagoryName = act.actioncategory.Name };
            return actions;
```

Do i need to write another replace function which will take actions as parameter do the processing of replacing the _ with space and return Iqueryable again.?

Help.

Thanks

Comment: Yes you need to write a separate function. Within linq queries it will not allow you to do string operations like remove("_", " ").

Comment: You can convert the returned collection into a list and perform an in-memory replace. You can return an IEnumerable.